# mockito mock static function does not work if the function is called in a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, static, mockito

android app, a java class needs to do something based on the NotificationManager's status.

```
class Util {
    
        static void setupByPermission(@NonNull final Context appContext) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        NotificationManagerCompat nm = NotificationManagerCompat.from(appContext);  // should got from stub
                        
                        boolean overallPermission = currentNotificationsPermission(nm);
                        if (overallPermission) {
                            doWithPermission();
                        } else {
                            doWithoutPermission();
                        }
                        
                    } catch (Throwable ex) {}
                }
            });
            t.start();
        }

    static boolean currentNotificationsPermission(@NonNull NotificationManagerCompat nm) {

        System.out.println("+++ enter currentNotificationsPermission("+nm+")");

        boolean overallPermission = nm.areNotificationsEnabled();// should got result from stub

        System.out.println("+++ ========= in currentNotificationsPermission("+nm+"), nm.areNotificationsEnabled() ==> "+overallPermission);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            if (overallPermission) {
                List<NotificationChannel> channels = nm.getNotificationChannels();
                boolean someChannelEnabled = channels.isEmpty();
                for (NotificationChannel channel : channels) {
                    if (channel.getImportance() != NotificationManagerCompat.IMPORTANCE_NONE) {
                        someChannelEnabled = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                overallPermission = overallPermission && someChannelEnabled;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("+++ --- exit =========== currentNotificationsPermission(), overallPermission:"+overallPermission);

        return overallPermission;
    }
    
}
```

would like to stub the `NotificationManagerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled()`
to force a test with the return of either true or false.

test using mockito-inline 3.8.0

```
@Test
public void test () throws Exception  {

   try (MockedStatic<NotificationManagerCompat> nmMoc = Mockito.mockStatic(NotificationManagerCompat.class);
        MockedStatic<Util> utilMoc = Mockito.mockStatic(Util.class)
        ) {

        NotificationManagerCompat nmSpy = spy(NotificationManagerCompat.from(application));
        
when(nmSpy.areNotificationsEnabled())
            .thenReturn(false);  //or true

        nmMoc.when(() -> NotificationManagerCompat.from(any(Context.class)))
            .thenReturn(nmSpy);

        // test
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        utilMoc.setupByPermission(application);
        latch.await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Mockito.verify(......);
        }
}
```

but the stub is not called when they are in the Thread. same if stub the `currentNotificationsPermission()`.

Hot to make the stub for a static function to work in the the thread?

Comment: Why are you mocking `Util`? Isn't that the class you're testing?

Comment: there are more functions in it and in the exec path, which are to be verified (not included in the snippet here).

Comment: Mocking static methods is a major smell.

Answer (score 3):

There seem to be a few things wrong with your test:

- Don't mock static methods. Refactor your code to use an interface and an implementation. This will make dependency injection easier too.
- Read the Javadoc for `MockedStatic`. It explicitly tells you that the mock works only on the original thread.
- How does your code compile? `utilMoc` is a `MockedStatic<Util>` so how can you call `setupByPermission` on it?
- Given that you've mocked `Util`, calling methods on `Util` will not call the 'real' method anyway, unless you tell it to. See the example below.
- Unit testing multithreaded code is difficult. Have a component which is responsible for executing `Runnable`. In your tests use a dummy implementation which runs the `Runnable` on the current thread.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.MockedStatic;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class TestExample {
    public static class Foo {
        public static String bar() {
            return "bar";
        }
    }
    @Test
    public void aTest() {
        try (MockedStatic<Foo> foo = Mockito.mockStatic(Foo.class)) {
// without this line Foo.bar() will return null
            when(Foo.bar()).thenCallRealMethod();
            assertThat(Foo.bar()).isEqualTo("bar");
        }
    }
}
```

While people have put in a lot of work to make it *possible* to mock static methods, as you're seeing it still isn't straightforward. The refactoring needed to avoid it *is* straightforward and has other benefits.

Comment: You can also set default behavior to call real method by writing `foo = Mockito.mockStatic(Foo.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)) { ...`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, I had missed to add the second parameter - Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS and the static mock wasn't happening. Thanks for putting this here.